# Fitting problem for sigmoid like experimental data

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I have data like this

```
data={{-83, 7.09531}, {-20, 1.65586}, {-10, 3.80134}, {0, 7.53841}, {0.2, 7.17162}, {0.3, 1.58444}, {0.8, 8.85609}, {2., 1.32255}, {8, 9.38444}, {20, 10}, {30, 40}, {40, 100}, {50, 550}, {80, 450}, {150,400}, {200, 431.727}, {240, 403.676}, {250, 442.495}, {312.2, 433.578}, {426.5, 410.929}, {480, 438.634}, {500, 447.573}, {550, 404.358}, {600, 429.312}}
```

I think I can fit with two different type of functions.
Since the data resembles to step function or sigmoid, but it has small peak at around inflection point.

1)Assuming that the data is step function with some parabolic curve,

```
func1[x_, c1_, c2_, k1_, k2_, a_, b_, h_] := Piecewise[{{c1, x < k1}, {a/(x - h)^2 + b, k1 <= x <= k2}, {c2, x > k2}}];
```

Then I tried to show the fitting and data together by executing

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, func1[x, c1, c2, k1, k2, a, b, h], {{c1, 5}, {c2, 440}, {k1, 5}, {k2, 40}, a, b, h}, x]
```

However, c2=317 which is about 100 smaller than the data. Also k1=k2=1, which is also strange. I think Fitting value is not proper.

2)I also tried sigmoid fitting pattern,

```
func2 = a/(1 + b*Exp[- (x - d)]);

ff2 = NonlinearModelFit[data, {func2, 30 < d < 100}, {a, b, d}, x]
```

The answer was {a -> 410.734, b -> -14.8102, d -> 31.3746}. Parameter a seems OK, however, when I visualize it by

```
Show[Plot[ff2[x], {x, -100, 600}], ListPlot[data], PlotRange -> All]
```

ff2 was strange shape, only to find that the fitting was failed. (Thanks to JimB, I could visualize it!)

I wonder if someone help me to get proper fitting.

Comment: Please say what doesn't work.  Do you get unrealistic estimates?  Do you get error messages?

Comment: You should remove the underscores in the `nlm` statement.

Comment: Thank you for the precious comment. For Func1, at first, there was error message and couldn't get answer. Now, after removing "_", I can get answer, but fitting was no good. ( I saw the data with   " Show[Plot[nlm[x], {x, -100, 600}], ListPlot[data], 
 PlotRange -> {{-100, 600}, {-100, 600}}] "). I want to know how to get proper fitting.

Comment: In func2, some answer comes back, but fitting data is not shown in the graph, with "Show[Plot[ff2[x], {x, -100, 600}], ListPlot[data], PlotRange -> {{-100, 600}, {-100, 600}}] ". So I thought this didn't work.

Comment: Those issues need to be described in your question rather than the comments.  In the meantime add `PlotRange -> All` to both plots.  In `func2` choose starting values other than the default of 1 especially for `k1` and `k2`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, what you said is correct, I should have written them in question. I am editting now...

Comment: To repeat:  take out the underscores in `nlm` and put in reasonable starting values that can be discerned from the plot of the data.  For example:  `{{c1, 5}, {c2, 440}, {k1, 5}, {k2, 40}, a, b, h}`.  For `ff2` use `NonlinearModelFit` rather than `FindFit`  as `FindFit` does not directly produce the output needed for `Plot`.